# How to collect object files (.o) in a particular directory with CMake?

Tags: cmake

CMake sets directories for objects files implicitly while compiling the source files, but I want to keep all those object files in a particular directory.

For example in my code CMake is creating directories based on the source code directories itself like this:

```
CMakeFiles/OBJ2.dir/src/lib/kernels/XnnKernel.o
```

I want to keep them in different locations, but unable to do so.

I tried some commands:

```
set(OBJ "build/CMakeFiles/OBJ1.dir/src/lib/kernels/igemm8_generic.o")
file(COPY ${OBJ} DESTINATION ${SOURCE_PATH}/src/OBJ_FILES)
```

As per my understanding, the `file(COPY)` command is getting executed before compilation. Please correct me if I am wrong and give me a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a combination of [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) expressions with a [custom](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) command. The basic functionality is based on the CMake capability of creating [object](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html) libraries.

project structure:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    └── foo.c
```

sample `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

project(foo C)

set(SOURCES "src/foo.c")

set(LIBNAME "foo")
set(LIBNAME_OBJ "${LIBNAME}_obj")

add_library(${LIBNAME_OBJ} OBJECT ${SOURCES})

target_include_directories(${LIBNAME_OBJ} PUBLIC "include")
target_compile_options(${LIBNAME_OBJ} PUBLIC "-fPIC")

add_library(${LIBNAME} SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${LIBNAME_OBJ}>)

set(OBJ_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/obj_dir)

add_custom_command(TARGET ${LIBNAME}
  POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${OBJ_DIR}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different 
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${LIBNAME_OBJ}> ${OBJ_DIR})
```

The [`file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#filesystem) command does not support generator expressions with filesystem operations.