# How to collect all object files (.o) of a big project in a particular directory with CMake?

Tags: cmake

I want to collect object files (.o) in a particular directory with CMake

I have tried the below snippet from [How to collect object files (.o) in a particular directory with CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50684930/how-to-collect-object-files-o-in-a-particular-directory-with-cmake)

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${LIBNAME}
  POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${OBJ_DIR}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different 
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${LIBNAME_OBJ}> ${OBJ_DIR})
```

The command **copy_if_different** works well when the library contains less number of sources and fails when it's more.
How to collect objects of a project which contains huge number of sources ?

Comment: You need to be specific about this threshold. What does "huge" mean? How many files? If it is too big maybe try doing that with an external script (e.g., in `bash`) and call that from a CMake custom command.

Answer (score 0):

For `add_custom_command` to execute its `COMMAND` arguments, something has to create a process environment for the command to execute in. Whether that's done by a command shell or directly using `exec()`, the size limit for that environment is defined by the `limits.h` macro `ARG_MAX`. On POSIX systems, `getconf ARG_MAX` will show the compile-time value of that configuration. On my Fedora 35 system, the value is `2097152` which seems almost impossible to exceed, but maybe you're dealing with smaller limits.

(Also, the `ARG_MAX` limit represents the **entire** environment, not just command arguments. So if there are a lot of environment variables defined, that could eat into your max length.)

If you truly are exceeding that, you have two choices:

##### Option 1: Install the objects in the install stage, as intended

If I'm understanding the linked q&a correctly, the only reason you need the `$<TARGET_OBJECTS>` paths is so that you can copy them somewhere else in the build tree, in order to then install them from there?

If you just want to install them, a simpler solution is to write custom install code, e.g.

```
# necessary because config variables aren't present
# in the install context.
install(CODE "set(OBJECT_DEST \"${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}\")"
  
install(CODE [[
  file(INSTALL
    DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${OBJECT_DEST}"
    FILES
      $<TARGET_OBJECTS:_actual_object_name_>
  )]])
```

Messing around with keeping the object name in a variable is a mistake when using custom install code, IMHO, as the evaluation contexts get too confusing. Instead of `${LIBNAME_OBJ}`, just use the actual target name in the generator expression.<sup>1</sup>

Since the generator-expression expansion is handled by CMake when generating the `cmake_install.cmake` script, there shouldn't be any limit on the length it can have. (Not beyond whatever limits it has internally, if any.)

##### Option 2: Break up your targets

If you really want to use `add_custom_command` with the objects, you'll need smaller targets. Why do all of your sources have to be defined on a single object library? Just break them up:

```
set(SOURCES1 a.c b.c c.c d.c)
set(SOURCES2 w.c x.c y.c z.c)

add_library(s1_obj OBJECT ${SOURCES1})
add_library(s2_obj OBJECT ${SOURCES2})

add_executable(foo
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:s1_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:s2_obj>
)

add_custom_target(copy_all_objs
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${OBJ_ROOT_DIR}/myobjects/
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:s1_obj>
    ${OBJ_ROOT_DIR}/myobjects/ 
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:s2_obj>
    ${OBJ_ROOT_DIR}/myobjects/ 
  COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS)
```

###### Notes

1. Actually, I typically recommend using real target names whenever possible in generator expressions.

   With some targets — at least `SHARED`, `STATIC`, `MODULE` and `ARCHIVE` libraries, plus executables — the target name defines the default output file name. So, I get using a variable for the name. (Though, I did say *default* — it can be overridden with the `OUTPUT_NAME` target property, and often that's a better way to make filenames configurable. And it lets you keep static target names.)

   But for targets like `INTERFACE`, `OBJECT`, and `ALIAS` libraries, the target name is meaningless — it's only used internally in the CMake code. There's no reason not to just hardcode it.

   If you're doing this in a macro/function and the target name *has* to be in a variable, your best bet is probably to write the `install()` code as a quoted argument rather than a bracket argument, so that variables get evaluated immediately. Which means lots of fun escaping, for the things you *don't* want evaluated immediately. (Though you can lose the `OBJECT_DEST` variable, at least.):

   ```
   install(CODE "
     file(INSTALL
       DESTINATION
         \"\$\{CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX\}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}\"
       FILES
         $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${LIBNAME_OBJ}>
     )")
   ```